# Why Apache2 (Ubuntu) run defferent with Apache(easyPHP server on Window)?

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, easyphp

I have a draft class:(*Update*)

```
class abb{
   static $fieldSelect;
   function init() {
        self::$field = require_once('inputs/Mapping.php');
   }
   function getField($item) {
        return self::$fieldSelect[$item];
   }
}
```

and `Mapping.php` contain:

```
<?php
return array(
    ItemType::Food          => 0.7,
    ItemType::Fashion       => 0.5,
);
```

It runs well on easyPHP(windows 7), but when I deploy it onto Apache2(Unbutu), an error exception appears. For example, I input `$item = "Phone"` (*Update here*), Apache2 throws exception:`Undefined index: Phone` at line `return self::$fieldSelect[$item];` If `$fieldSelect[$item]` does not exist, sever on Window will be return `NULL` but Ubuntu is not. I just wana see the different between Window and Ubuntu when run it.

I don't understand why it is so?

Comment: And how do you define `ItemType` enumeration? Have you tried `$item = ItemType::Food`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see `$fieldSelect` declared anywhere in your class. Perhaps you should be using `$field` instead?

You are also using `$fields` and `$field`.

Perhaps this will do:

```
class abb{ 
   static $fields; 
   function init() { 
        self::$fields = require_once('inputs/Mapping.php'); 
   } 
   function getField($item) { 
        return self::$fields[$item]; 
   } 
}
```

Finally, you will need to address the array key properly. I am not sure what your `ItemType` is defined as. Maybe using `$item = ItemType::Food` to access the key would help.

Comment: Oh I'm sory, when copy and edit I make mistake. You're right. And I just updated right now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume that the [error reporting level](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) was configured differently on the different systems.